# How to resolve unmet dependencies between containerd and runc?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am getting this error when I want to install docker.io (`sudo apt-get install docker.io`)

he following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
containerd.io : Conflicts: containerd
Conflicts: runc
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

I have tried to reinstall the containerd and runc but didn't solve the problem.

Comment: `docker.io` is an old package. Follow the installation instructions here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**try this**

`sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io containerd runc`

`sudo apt-get purge docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin docker-compose`

`sudo rm -rf /etc/bash_completion.d/docker /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /etc/bash_completion.d/docker-compose`

`sudo apt install containerd -y`

`sudo apt install -y docker.io docker-compose`